# Why does Runtime.freeMemory() change only when I create a large object?

Tags: java

Why does this program print 0 when I create new byte[1000] and 1000016 for new byte[1000 * 1000]?

```
    long m0 = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    Object obj = new byte[1000];
    long m1 = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    System.out.println(m0 - m1);
```

Comment: [Runtime.freeMemory()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory()) is an approximation of the available memory, it is not an accurate calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenJDK/Oracle HotSpot JVM uses a TLAB (Thread Local Allocation Buffer) to support concurrent object allocation.  This means each thread grabs lumps of memory for it to use.  If you turn this off, you will see accurate memory accounting.

Run with `-XX:-UseTLAB`

```
long m0 = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
Object obj = new Object();
long m1 = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
if (m1 == m0)
    throw new AssertionError("Please disable the TLAB with -XX:-UseTLAB");
System.out.println(m0 - m1);
```

prints

```
16
```

Comment: Does it mean that new byte[1000] in my test is created not on heap?

Comment: By default it is created in a Thread Local Allocation Buffer (which is in the Eden space of the heap) and the freeMemory() doesn't see how much of these are used. If you turn off the TLAB you can see exactly how much memory is used.